# How to implement a Java back end to put web form input into a database?

Tags: java, html

So if you want to take input from an html form and put that into a database, you can have the form's action direct to a php file like example.php.  That php file can then manage database calls with like mysqli_connect() and whatnot.

My question is, what is the equivalent of this when you want to use a Java back end instead?  Do I have the form's action direct to a .java file?  I know how to use Hibernate for databases, but I don't know how to connect the input from the web form to my Java code.

I have no clue what terms to even google for.  I tried "java back end tutorial" but that wasn't useful at all.  I'd appreciate any simple explanations, or even the correct technologies to look up.

Comment: You can use a servlet or a jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop Web application and Web site with Java. Google it and you will see a lot of tutorials on how to do it.
The initial technology to develop Web apps with Java is `Servlet` or `JSP` as said above by user2963623.

Comment: Just a little new contribution. You can use JAX-RS (a Java EE spécification) implémentation of RESTful web services with Jersey or other implémentation available.